# File Mime type is always null

Tags: android, kotlin

The next code consistently throws an exception since the URI is "file:///" instead of "content://". I believe this discrepancy is the root of the issue. How can we resolve it?

```
`val type = contentResolver.getType(file.toUri()).orEmpty()
            when {
                type.contains("image") -> {
                    compressImage(file)
                }

                type.contains("video") -> {
                    compressVideo(file.path, {}, {}) ?: file
                }

                else -> {
                    e { file.toUri().toString() }
                    throw Exception("Unsupported File Type")
                }
            }`
```